# SQL join two rows in one by an identificator. Query

Tags: sql-server

I hope that someone can help me to do this.

I have this result of a query that have the id with the columns of the 2 providers that is a bool parameter,

`Id   Prov1   Prov210   true   false10   false   true`

with this result I want to join the result in one row with SQL 2008, that finish:

`Id   Prov1   Prov210   true   true`

There are a form to do this with a query?,

Thanks.

Comment: What do you call a `bool parameter` in SQL Server? Post your complete query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT t.Id, MAX(t.Prov1), MAX(t.Prov2) 
FROM MyTable t
GROUP BY t.Id
```

Comment: Thanks, a simple but effective solution.